# Converting a date variable from double to long

Tags: date, stata

I have a date variable in Stata which is stored as a `double` which looks like this:

```
Date
07dec2012
08jan2018
    .
    . 
    .
```

The display format is: `%td`. I would like to convert this variable into a `long` format so that I can use it for a fixed effects analysis. Is there an easy way of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long` is a variable or storage type, not a (display) format.

Daily dates that arise in most practice can be stored as `int` variables, so `compress` will achieve that.

```
. clear

. set obs 1
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1.

. gen double date = mdy(1, 8, 2018)

. compress
  variable date was double now int
```

I wasn't aware that being `double` would be a problem for what you want to do, and I can't see why `long` should be preferred over `int`.

EDIT The reported range of dates can be tested too

```
. clear

. set obs 2
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 2.

. gen double Date = cond(_n==1, -19903, 22280)



. format Date %td

. l

     +-----------+
     |      Date |
     |-----------|
  1. | 05jul1905 |
  2. | 31dec2020 |
     +-----------+

. compress Date
  variable Date was double now int
  (12 bytes saved)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. When I run "compress date" the storage type doesn't change. It just displays (0 bytes saved) and the storage type is still double. Also when you generate "gen double date = mdy(1, 8, 2018)" the entry becomes "21192". The way may data is saved is in the 07dec2012 format.

Comment: Naturally, I did not specify a daily date display format because it is not needed for the question which is how to get a different storage type. More importantly, the reason you can't `compress` is likely to be junk in your variable that is the reason why it is `double` in the first place. Run `summarize Date` and tell us what is the largest value shown.

Comment: It has mean 20373.12, max 22280 and min -19903.

Comment: That should be OK. Please see EDIT. Do you have any missing values? `list if missing(Date)`.

Comment: I just checked and there were missing observations. But even after dropping them, after running compress date STATA still only displays "(0 bytes saved)"

Comment: I am out of ideas. Does Stata [NB] still tell you that `Date` is `double`?

Comment: Yes it unfortunately does.

Comment: OK; do you have non-integer values? `list if Date != floor(Date)`

Comment: Yes apparently I have 43. Could that be the root of the problem?

Comment: If I delete the non integer values and I compress date it works! Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: So, where did the non-integers come from? Certainly `long` cannot hold fractional parts and `double` won't compress even to `float` unless the fractional parts are very simple.

Comment: I'm not sure. When I run  list date if date != floor(date) I get 43 observations but the dates seem like any other dates in the dataset with in same %td format

Comment: Are they exactly as imported or else how did you create the `Date` variable.? The format `%td` ignores fractional parts -- that is part of its job -- on the grounds that it is (say) 1 June 2022 all day long. Fractional days don't trouble it. Try `di %td 22797.654`

Comment: You can do that in one line as `gen fmdy = mdy(month(financingstartdate), ..., ...)` where the ... are similar code. but `gen fmdy = floor(financingstartdate)` is even more direct.

Comment: I found a workaround without dropping the observations: I can generate variables for day month and year as such: gen fday=day(financingstartdate)
gen fmonth=month(financingstartdate)
gen fyear=year(financingstartdate)
I can then generate: gen fmdy=mdy(fmonth,fday,fyear)
format fmdy %td